# Python SQLite Updating Column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to update an album_title column based on the artist_title column which is already populated.

I can either make the whole album_title column update with the last album_title in the loop reapeatdly:
for tag in albums:

```
for album in tag:
    cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Albums (album_title) VALUES (?)', (album, ))

    for artist in artists:
        artist = artist.string          
        cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artists(artist_name) VALUES (?)', (artist, ))        
        cur.execute('UPDATE Artists SET album_title=? WHERE artist_name=?', (album, artist))
```

Or I can make only the last row update with the correct album_title.

```
 for tag in albums:

    for album in tag:
        cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Albums (album_title) VALUES (?)', (album, ))

        for artist in artists:
            artist = artist.string          
            cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artists(artist_name) VALUES (?)', (artist, ))

        cur.execute('UPDATE Artists SET album_title=? WHERE artist_name=?', (album, artist))
```

I understand why these issues are happening, but I cannot work out how to achieve what I want - every row updated with correct album names.
The album_title names will always be in the same order as the artist_name.

I have seen that updating columns is covered extensively here, but I cannot work this out due to  the unique for loops I have got myself tangled in.
If my problem is because I have structured my data retrieval badly, I'd be happy to hear how to fix it.

Entire Code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib.error
import sqlite3
import json
import time
import ssl


#connect/create database
conn = sqlite3.connect('pitchscraper.sqlite')
#create way to talk to database
cur = conn.cursor()

#create table
cur.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Master (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, album_title TEXT UNIQUE, artist_name TEXT UNIQUE)''')

cur.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Albums (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, album_title TEXT UNIQUE)''')

cur.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Artists (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, artist_name TEXT UNIQUE, album_title TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(album_title) REFERENCES Albums(album_title))''')



#open and read page
req = Request('http://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/?page=1', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
pitchpage = urlopen(req).read()


#parse with beautiful soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(pitchpage, "lxml")
albums = soup('h2')
artists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "artist-list"})


for tag in albums:

    for album in tag:
        cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Albums (album_title) VALUES (?)', (album, ))

        for artist in artists:
            artist = artist.string          
            cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artists(artist_name) VALUES (?)', (artist, ))        
            cur.execute('UPDATE Artists SET album_title=? WHERE artist_name=?', (album, artist))


print()


conn.commit()
```

Failed Output:

```
+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
|  id  |                artist_name                | album_title |
+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| "1"  | "Sylvan Esso"                             | "Odd Hours" |
| "2"  | "Mew"                                     | "Odd Hours" |
| "3"  | "Tara Jane O’Neil"                        | "Odd Hours" |
| "4"  | "Real Life Buildings"                     | "Odd Hours" |
| "5"  | "Bruce Springsteen and the E Street Band" | "Odd Hours" |
| "6"  | "Ravyn Lenae"                             | "Odd Hours" |
| "7"  | "Tee Grizzley"                            | "Odd Hours" |
| "8"  | "Shugo Tokumaru"                          | "Odd Hours" |
| "9"  | "Woods"                                   | "Odd Hours" |
| "10" | "Formation"                               | "Odd Hours" |
| "11" | "Valgeir Sigurðsson"                      | "Odd Hours" |
| "12" | "Caddywhompus"                            | "Odd Hours" |
+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  id  |                artist_name                |          album_title          |
+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| "1"  | "Sylvan Esso"                             | "What Now"                    |
| "2"  | "Mew"                                     | "Visuals"                     |
| "3"  | "Tara Jane O’Neil"                        | "Tara Jane O'Neil"            |
| "4"  | "Real Life Buildings"                     | "Significant Weather"         |
| "5"  | "Bruce Springsteen and the E Street Band" | "Hammersmirth Odeon, London"  |
| "6"  | "Ravyn Lenae"                             | "Midnight Moonlight EP"       |
| "7"  | "Tee Grizzley"                            | "My Moment"                   |
| "8"  | "Shugo Tokumaru"                          | "TOSS"                        |
| "9"  | "Woods"                                   | "Love is Love"                |
| "10" | "Formation"                               | "Look at the Powerful People" |
| "11" | "Valgeir Sigurðsson"                      | "Dissonance"                  |
| "12" | "Caddywhompus"                            | "Odd Hours"                   |
+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: @CL. I added 2 screenshots for you.

Comment: Show the desired result. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125))

Comment: @CL. Done. Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: The code looks OK. Are you sure the source data is correcT?

Comment: @CL. yep, very sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
albums = soup('h2')
artists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "artist-list"})
```

The problem is that the `artists` list contains *all* artists.

You have to extract the artist list inside the loop, from each individual album.

Comment: Not sure I understand, could you give a bit more detail please?